# Multiple projects with the same Authentication system in (Asp.Net MVC / Web-Api)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, authorization, restful-authentication

I have several projects such as `After Sales Service` and `Product Label Generator` that their users are the same, I mean users can register and according to admin's decision can have some roles or claims.

Depending on roles or claims, each user has access to a specific application.

In my opinion I should create a web-api app in order to just serve authentication and authorization services.

It should be noted that we may go further and have some other apps such as android version. also each project has its own database.

What's the problem? I have no idea how I can implement this! any suggestion or article can help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hooman, I would suggest you to use IdentityServer for authentication, it's Open Source OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 framework for .NET. We are also in process of using it,nature of yours and ours products looks same to me. Keeping a single database for users and their rights and also managing access/rights for specific applications. As it's also token based, so if u extend your products to Mobile later on, it would prove to be a better approach as well.

link: https://identityserver.io/
documentation looks self sufficient to me.